# Hide #NA displayed in the cell by formula =IFERROR(~~~,NA())

Tags: excel, charts, formatting

I'm trying to format my excel sheet and to display organized chart, I have to do( A1~A100 )

```
IFERROR($B1+$C1,NA())
```

To make cells #NA value instead of

```
IFERROR($B1+$C1,"")
IFERROR($B1+$C1,"-")
```

because those "" or "-" is going to be shown as 0 value on chart and it looks really bad on sight.

But I don't want #NA to be shown on my cells. It's clearly makes my sheet looks messy.

I tried to do Conditional Formatting to do
'New Rule...'→'Use a formula to determine which cells to format'→=ISNA(A1)→white blank
It worked but since the rule only applies only when "A1" is not #NA and not to others, I don't think this is a practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your formatting `=ISNA($A1)` then drag down copy the cell after clicking apply.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other choice than using **range1** (your current range) for calc and as chart source, then create **range2** pointing to range1 using IFERROR, then finally *hiding* **range1**.
A bit clumsy, but that's the only way I see here to separate data from presentation.